# Why can't I read my data from my serial port?

Tags: python, pyserial

Why is this code not working?

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1')
#s.open()

s.write(b"1234")
print(s.read())
print(s.read_all())
```

When I run this code, I get this output:

```
b'1'
b''
```

Comment: hope you ensured that port is opened for python to access

Comment: What's connected to the port? Does it understand what you're trying to send it?

Comment: hi Nega kiran and thank you for your comment.

yeah my port is opened and not problem for your guess!

Comment: hi AKX and i know averything about my port connect and my port is writable.
and Thank You For Your comment :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is on Information about any device connected and the output is empty the second time I assume you need a delay or some kind of waiting in your code. This is because the machine you are running the python script on executes much faster than your baudrate of the serial device.

Try this for example:

```py
import serial
import time

s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB1')
s.write(b'1234')

time.sleep(1)

print(s.read_all())
```